why can't I display the html page in nginx
good afternoon, I ran into the problem that I can't display the html code in nginx
I have a configuration file that looks like this
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        server {
                location / {
                        index index.html;
                        root /home/user/site;
                }
        }
}

there is an html file at the path specified in the root

but when I go to the ip address I get an error

when starting, the error does not crash, but when I try to access the site, I get an error
I put nginx through the command
apt install nginx

the content of the html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<p>word</p>

</body>
</html>

